# java.lang.SecurityException despite INTERNET permission being in the manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am getting the following error when I run my application on my phone:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

I have already added that permission in my manifest file as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I am getting the error only when I run the app on my phone. It runs fine on my GenyMotion emulator. I read similar questions on SO before posting it. Also, I have made a couple of apps before with same permissions, and this error had never occurred then. So I don't get why Android is messing it up this time.

P.S.: I updated my SDK tools before starting with this new application. Somehow felt that it was important to mention it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use small caps

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```